# How to render cart after reload, using Session Storage?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to render cart after reload, bun I could only add keys of session in browser's memory for each element. After reload elements of cart disappear.

Can you help to understand how to add goods to cart after reload browser using session storage's keys.

Thank you in advance!

```js
// data
let jsonFile = [
    { "id": "001", "name": "Hoody Green", "desc": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", "price": 65.00 },
    { "id": "002", "name": "Cap Pink", "desc": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", "price": 35.00 },
    { "id": "003", "name": "Cap Black", "desc": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", "price": 25.00, }
];

// get dom elements
const productsContainer = document.getElementById('content');
const cartContainer = document.getElementById('cart');

// reduce json data
const products = jsonFile.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
    accumulator[current.id] = current;
    return accumulator;
}, {}); // { id: {id, name, price}, }
const cart = {}; // { id: quantity }

// render Product Item
const renderProductItem = data => {
    const { id, name, price, desc } = data;
    return `
      <div class="item">
        <p>ID - ${id}</p>
        <h2>${name}</h2>
        <p>${desc}</p>
        <b>${price}</b>
        <div class="goods__btn">
          <button class="minus" onclick="minus('${id}')">&minus;</button>
          <button class="plus" onclick="plus('${id}')">&plus;</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    `;
};

// render Cart Item
const renderCartItem = data => {
    const { id, name, price, quantity } = data;
    return `
        <div class="cart-item">
            ID ${id} (${name}): ${quantity} pcs.
            <button class="minus" onclick="minus('${id}')">&minus;</button>
            <button class="plus" onclick="plus('${id}')">&plus;</button>
            =$${price * quantity}
        </div>
    `;
};

// render cart / render products
const getCartTotal = () =>
    Object.entries(cart)
        .map(([id, quantity]) => products[id].price * quantity)
        .reduce((sum, current) => sum + current);

const renderCart = () => {
    if (Object.keys(cart).length === 0) {
        cartContainer.innerHTML = 'Cart is empty';
        return;
    } cartContainer.innerHTML =
        Object.entries(cart)
            .map(([id, quantity]) => renderCartItem({ ...products[id], quantity }))
            .join('') + `<div class="cart-total">Total: ${getCartTotal()}$</div>`;
};
const showProducts = products => {
    productsContainer.innerHTML = Object.values(products)
        .map(renderProductItem)
        .join('');
};
showProducts(products);
renderCart();

// plus
const plus = id => {
    // sessionStorage.setItem(id, 'true');
    // if (sessionStorage.getItem(id) === 'true') {
        cart[id] ??= 0;
        cart[id]++;
    // }
    renderCart();
};

// minus
const minus = id => {
    if (cart[id]) {
        cart[id]--;
        if (cart[id] <= 0) {
            delete cart[id];
            // sessionStorage.removeItem(id);
        }
        renderCart();
    }
};
```

```css
h1, h2, h3, p, a, b, span {
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #eee;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item {
  width: 30%;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
}

.cart {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  background: #ddd;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="goods">
        <div class="container" id="content">
        goods
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="cart">
        <div class="container" id="cart">
        cart
        </div>
    </section>
```

I'm trying to render cart after reload, bun I could only add keys of session in browser's memory for each element. After reload elements of cart disappear.

Can you help to understand how to add goods to cart after reload browser using session storage's keys.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To render a cart after reloading the page using session storage, you can follow these steps:

First, you will need to store the cart items in session storage. You can do this by calling the setItem method of the sessionStorage object and passing in the key and value for the cart items. For example:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cartItems));
```

When the page is reloaded, you can retrieve the cart items from session storage using the getItem method of the sessionStorage object. This will return a string representation of the cart items, which you will need to parse into a JavaScript object using the JSON.parse method. For example:

let cartItems = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("cart"));
Once you have retrieved the cart items from session storage, you can loop through them and render them on the page. You can do this using JavaScript and a library like jQuery to manipulate the page's HTML elements. For example:

```
for (let item of cartItems) {
let itemHTML = "<div>" + item.name + " - $" + item.price + "</div>";
$("#cart").append(itemHTML);
```

}
By following these steps, you can render a cart on the page after it has been reloaded, using session storage to persist the cart items